Removed com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 from dependencies and now force update is not showing up
While pushing the update for my App in Play console they flagged error with my bundle
update your com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 maven dependency to an android 14 compatible version! your current com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 library is incompatible with targetsdkversion 34 (android 14), which introduces a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers. as a reminder, from august 31, 2024, google play requires all new app releases to target android 14. update to the latest library version dependency to avoid app crashes
to resolve the issue, As mentioned in https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration I have Updated
com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3
with
implementation 'com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:review-ktx:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.1.0'

and pushed the update in Play console.
Now as the review is approved I'm not receiving force update in my previous versions which was working fine on last update.
Pls help..
